# Reversal didn't work as expected

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday I was the victim of a serial downvote, where they randomly voted 4 times in different posts, but the system only reversed the equivalent of 3. On other network sites, I have been a victim of "serial upvote" a few times and always the system reverted correctly, removing all reputation equivalent to the votes in series.

[image]

Is this behavior expected by the reversal? This is not the first time I'm a serial downvote victim and the system does not reverts correctly.

Comment: That 4th vote may just have been bad timing. It may be unrelated.

Comment: @Cerbrus I participate in other SO's  , where also occurred the same thing.

Comment: Ah, of course. I always forget about those. My apologies.

Comment: This is similar to something happend to me, I think that the fact that the first downvote was on 14:58 and the rest of the DVs were a minute late made the script ignore the first one, but it was reverted eventually ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299735/unexplained-undownvote-after-4-days-on-an-unedited-post))

Comment: That 4th post also got upvoted.  Which is pretty odd on a post that has been dormant for a year.  So sure, it is not unexpected for the machine to think that it probably shouldn't revert that one.

Comment: From what I can see on the mod tools (they only allow us to see certain things and never specific votes) - the vote reversal tool has done what it's supposed do it... and one vote might just well fit the criteria...

Comment: I don't understand why anyone do this to a person who rarely participates here, what motivated he had.

Comment: @Articuno Let's just say that serial DV are common enough that there's a daily script to handle and revert them...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWNXt.jpg Sometimes the reversal script doesn't catch all the votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The serial downvoting script is conservative by design, so sometimes it gets part of a streak of votes and not the remainder. Sometimes, these votes came from different people and were just coincidental.

In this case, I think the script missed one, because you weren't the only person that was targeted with serial downvotes by this person. Some of the others they left for other people were missed as well, so I've requested that community managers look into it.

I normally wouldn't ping them over a single missed vote, but given the multiple users impacted by this I thought they should take a look. Again, this does happen from time to time with the script and its relatively high thresholds for detecting serial voting.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be waiting for a resolution.